# Unplugging cooking utensil from timer on Yom Tov?

Tags: halacha, yom-tov, muktzeh, electricity

Suppose that someone has an electronic cooking utensil such as a Crock Pot or a rice cooker that they use on Yom Tov. Perhaps they set a timer before Y"T in order that it should start cooking during the holiday.

If that electric appliance is plugged into an outlet that is regulated with a timer, can the appliance be unplugged when the timer is in the off condition such that the outlet is not functioning?

To me, it seems like something that should not be permitted, but I cannot think of a reason why it would not be. On Shabbos, there would be an issue of muktzeh, but I do not believe that such a utensil would be considered muktzeh on Yom Tov where its work is permitted.

**For the purpose of this question, assume that the timer going to the "off" position completely cuts off the flow of electricity to the appliance.  I am not sure whether this is actually the case.  If you happen to know, please provide that information!**

Comment: You want to unplug the utensil from the timer, or the timer from the wall? (I'm thinking of the classic dial-timer with the pins clicked in and out.)

Comment: @DoubleAA Yeah, that's the kind I'm thinking of also. I'm talking about unplugging the utensil from the timer.

Comment: I believe all electronic devices still draw a minimal amount of electricity even in the off position. An LED TV might draw, for example, a few watts-per-hour even while turned off. In other words, If the cooking utensil has any LED's or clock or and stand-by light on, it surely is drawing power. Even if doesn't, it can still be drawing a trickle of power.

Comment: @JeffreyLevine Are you sure that's true even if it's not plugged directly into the outlet, but rather into a timer which is off? I know that the timer is definitely still drawing some power becaues the dial continues to turn. But is the appliance which is plugged into an off timer which is plugged into the wall drawing power?

Comment: Hey Daniel. I wouldn't "swear to it" but I imagine that there would still be a trickle going to the appliance. I am told that turning the switch off of a powerstrip does cut the electrical flow to the attached item so it is possible that a timer in the off position would act the same. I'll try to get a more definitive answer for you Daniel.

Comment: @JeffreyLevine Please do. I'm interested in hearing what you find out. Why would you think that it wouldn't work that way?

Comment: @JeffreyLevine, That's an interesting point. I'm not sure whether such a trickle charge would be of Halachic significance if it has no function.

Comment: Hello Daniel. give me some more time, perhaps I'll have a definitve answer after shabbos. Shabbot Shalom. Jeffrey

Comment: Daniel, I tried my best and asked several people who I assumed could answer your question. They did not know the answer. I forget what they're called, but you can ask in a hardware store for a simple and inexpensive wired devise that lights if it detects elctricity. (It's used to determine whether or not an electric socket is live.) It is both safe and easy to use. Plug the timer in, have it set to OFF and measure the current on the timers socket, ie, where you would plug something into the timer. If there is no indicator of current, you may have your answer!

Comment: Daniel, on more thing. Just remember to make sure the outlet that the timer is plugged into is on!

Comment: @JeffreyLevine I don't think an [ammeter](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ammeter) would work to determine if electricity is flowing in an outlet because electrical outlets use AC rather than DC.

Comment: A digital multi meter will work. Check out http://www.ehow.com/how_5840711_test-electrical-outlet-digital-multimeter.html.  They give step by step instructions. The item I couldn't think of before is called a voltage tester.

Comment: @JeffreyLevine An off timer should not permit electricity through it.  Otherwise, the device it plugged into would be on.  Try it with a simple lame with an incandescent bulb. If any electricity came through, the bulb would be lit.

Answer (score 1):

If it has been turned off by a shabbat clock (timer), I don't see any problem with unplugging it, as one is merely preventing it from turning on again.

Comment: @CharlesKoppelman No problem with muktzeh?

Comment: @Daniel, wouldn't Muktzeh also apply on Yom Tov?