# Covering a preprogrammed remote control on Shabbos

Tags: halacha, shabbat, contemporary-halacha, lighting

If there was a device set up before Shabbos that every hour would send an IR (infrared) signal towards an appliance such as a fireplace to either turn it on or off, would one be allowed to cover that device with a cup to prevent the signal from activating the appliance on Shabbos? Infrared is a spectrum of light, so wouldn't covering it be okay if one is allowed to cover lights on Shabbos (the Kosher Lamp an example)?

An example of such a device is the BroadLink RM4 Mini:
[https://www.amazon.com/BroadLink-Cable-WiFi-Automation-Controller-RM4/dp/B0872PPSGM/](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B0872PPSGM)

Edit:
The IR is sent as a short blast of invisible light.

However I also heard that grama devices are not Halachically ordained. I don't have the source.

**The Kosher Lamp:**

[image: Kosher Lamp]

**The BroadLink RM4 Mini which sends IR blasts:**

[image: BroadLink RM4 Mini]

Comment: To clarify: the IR is sent as a pulse? So at the moment you covered it, it would not be emitting anything, right?

Comment: I know that there have been a number of "gramma" devices built in the past that have used interrupting a scheduled beam of light as a mechanism to register input on Shabbat. One example is a gramma keypad, with 10 holes instead of buttons, and a beam of light that pulses underneath it every few seconds. To enter numbers, you put a stick into the hole, wait for the light to flash, put the stick into the next hole, wait for the light to flash again, etc. It seems to me that if this is allowed, your case should also be allowed, but I don't have the original sources to quote.

Comment: A timer that uses a piece that pushes the switch (somewhat old fashioned) should be similar. Removing the piece before it hits the switch is allowed, although some raise a muktzeh issue. If so, this case would be allowed since at the time of covering there was no light emanating

Comment: I edited my question. The IR is sent as a pulse.

Comment: If there was a (visible) light set to flash every hour, and you stood in front of it, would there be an issue? I think the issue with the IR would be what it is activating. If you blocking the beam turns on a light, you still turned on the light, no? I don't know that the intermittent nature adds to the degree of separation...

Comment: This already exists. I have a device that releases a lot of IR waves on a timer, and an object that performs a melacha when hit by enough of the waves. Arranging the two next to each other so that the one can influence the other is a classic case discussed in halacha and generally considered forbidden, see rama here https://he.wikisource.org/wiki/%D7%A9%D7%95%D7%9C%D7%97%D7%9F_%D7%A2%D7%A8%D7%95%D7%9A_%D7%90%D7%95%D7%A8%D7%97_%D7%97%D7%99%D7%99%D7%9D_%D7%A8%D7%A0%D7%92_%D7%94 who permits a gentile to do so but not a Jew. The device is called a "plata".

Comment: @DoubleAA Clever connection, but I don't think it's really the same thing. Food sitting on the plata is not "an object that performs a melacha when hit by enough of the waves" - the food is not *performing* anything. It makes more sense to compare to the relationship between the timer and the plata, as discussed [here](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/30817/unplugging-cooking-utensil-from-timer-on-yom-tov).

Comment: @MosheKatz how about "an object such that when hit by enough of the waves a melacha happens". Unplugging the plata from the timer while off is analogous to removing the food from a plata which is fine.

Comment: @BID The reason the intermittent nature adds to the degree of separation is because you are not actually performing any action that is directly connected to the result. When you stood in front of the light, nothing happened because the light was off, and when the light turned on, you didn't move to block it, you just happened to be already standing there.